# in core-plot how do i translate to coordinates using the plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex method?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-plot

i can see that in the mac version example, they have used binding and NSArrayController (both of which are not available in iOs?)

what i have from

```
(void)scatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

is the index and the plot in context.

I need to get the exact coordinates so that i can use a popover at that point.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you provided data to the scatter plot, you used the

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

delegate method (or something like that).  Part of the information it queried was the recordIndex, which is usually used as an index into an NSArray of your data points.

The delegate method you show there gives you back an index to indicate that a point on the scatter plot was interacted with.  You should be able to grab the X, Y coordinate that corresponds to that index in your data source array and use

```
double doublePrecisionPlotPoint[2];
doublePrecisionPlotPoint[CPCoordinateX] = [xValue doubleValue];
doublePrecisionPlotPoint[CPCoordinateY] = [yValue doubleValue];

CGPoint viewPoint = [graph.defaultPlotSpace plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint:doublePrecisionPlotPoint];
```

to obtain the view coordinate in the graph that corresponds to the data point location that was touched.  From there, you can do coordinate space conversions to get the appropriate location to place your annotation.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. i didn't understand the doubleprecisionpoint parameter could accept both the x and Y values.

Comment: @zecougar - Yes, the use of a C-style array isn't immediately made clear, unless you take a look at the framework source code.  I really need to get active with the framework again, because I wasn't even aware that this touch handling capability had been implemented.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated @BradLarson is there a new way of doing it nicely?

Comment: Yes: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CorePlot/1.4/Classes/CPTPlotSpace.html#//api/name/plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint: